# Error implementing Lightweight Service Orchestration for non-blocking backend services for WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I implement the scenario at http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/12/lightweight-service-orchestration-for-non-blocking-backend-services-using-wso2-esb/ I get an error that says

"Proxy Service requires a valid in sequence or valid endpoint".

is there something I am missing from this demo? It seems straightforward enough.  I have the latest ESB software as of today if that makes a difference. It is higher than 4.5 as the article says.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this sample, proxy xml definition must be outside **description** tag :

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="studentRegistrationProxy" transports="https http" startonload="true" trace="disable">
   <description></description>
   <target>
      <insequence>
         <clone>
             ...
         </clone>
      </insequence>
      <outsequence>
        <aggregate>
             ...
         </aggregate>
      </outsequence>
      <faultsequence>
      </faultsequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```